# Pythonic way to create list

Tags: python-3.x, list

How could I create a list in pythonic way?
I want something like that, but "mv_rand" brokes syntax.
moves = [previous_move for i in range(3), mv_rand]
(it's like, moves = [1, 1, 1, 2])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question it appears you are trying to have one option `previous_move` show up 3 times more often than the other `mv_rand` option. If that is correct you can do something like this:

```py
    moves = [previous_move] * 3 + [mv_rand]
    chosen_move = random.choice(moves)
```

This will create a `moves` list that looks like `moves = [previous_move, previous_move, previous_move, mv_rand]]` and then [`choice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#functions-for-sequences) will chose from that.

if you are using python 3 you can use `choices()` which allows you to give weightings to the options being selected from, like this:

```py
    moves = [previous_move, mv_rand]
    weights = [0.75, 0.25]
    chosen_move = random.choices(moves, weights=weights)
```

This will weight the first entry 3 times more in the chosen_move selection as the second option.

The docs for `choices()` are in the same link as for `choice()` above.

Comment: yessssss, thanks man that's exactly it. [Thank you] * 3 thousand

Answer (score 0):

I think this could help you.

```
from random import randint
moves = [randint(1,8) for i in range(3)]
print(moves)
```

Comment: yeah but I want one number to have 75% chance to be chosen